# How to combine "must" and "should" in Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to "translate" this pseudo-SQL query in Elasticsearch query DSL:

> select from invoice where invoiceType = 'REGULAR' and receiver =
>   'CUSTOMER' and (invoiceStatus = 'DISPATCHED' or invoiceStatus = 'PAYED')

I have this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "invoiceType":  "REGULAR" }},
        { "match": { "receiver": "CUSTOMER" }},
        { "bool" : {
            "should": [
                {"match" : {"invoiceStatus": "DISPATCHED"}},
                {"match" : {"invoiceStatus": "PAYED"}}
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That query is returning 0 results, but I know there are many that matches what I'm searching for. AFAIK, `must` would be like 'AND' and `should` like 'OR'. What am I missing?

Comment: The ES query you posted is "close enough" to the SQL query. What are the field types? Can you replace `match` with `term`. Also, one way of debugging would be to remove `must` conditions one by one and see what documents you get back.

Comment: Wow, @khachik Replacing match with term did the trick! Thank you very much. Can I know the difference?

Comment: The actual difference will depend on the field types, simply speaking "term" is an exact match with no analyzers applied. It is a larger topic to be discussed in a comment though :) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: @khachik Please, can you post it as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure that it will work for you or not but you can make a try and see what you get? Though I did some change with `match` to `term`. Hope this will help you.

```
GET /invoice/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                { "term" : {"invoiceType" : "REGULAR"}}, 
                { "term": { "receiver": "CUSTOMER" }},
                { "bool" : { 
                  "should" : [
                      {"terms": {"invoiceStatus": ["DISPATCHED","PAYED"]}}   
                  ]
                }}
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**OR**

```
GET /invoice/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                { "term" : {"invoiceType" : "REGULAR"}}, 
                { "term": { "receiver": "CUSTOMER" }},
                { "bool" : { 
                  "should" : [
                    {"term": {"invoiceStatus": "DISPATCHED"}},
                    {"term": {"invoiceStatus": "PAYED"}}     
                  ]
                }}
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: 0 results returned

Comment: for both case you get 0 results?

Comment: If result if still `0` then try to debug it one by one. For exmple: at first by `invoiceType` then `receiver` and finally with `invoiceStatus`. I hope you will get the result.

Comment: Thank you! I did debug it as you said. I solved by using term instead of match.

Comment: @Héctor glad it helps you some how. Best of luck.